# Splitting two types of strings in a column

Tags: python, pandas, string, strsplit

I have two types of strings in column "1234/123456789/12/123" and "1234/X/123456789/12/123" . I want to split it into five columns such whenever there is "X" in the string it goes to the second column, otherwise column 2 remains empty.
Expected Output

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
1234         123456789  12      123
1234     X   123456789  12      123
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @funie200 I have tried str.split("/", expand = T). But it puts the strings in the sequence. I wand column 2 empty when there is no character in the string.

Comment: Will "X" always be in the second position, or can it be anywhere? That is, is it possible the input to be "1234/123456789/X/12/123" and you still want X in Col2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is first use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for DataFrame, `rename` columns and then test second column if not equal `X`, then shifting all columns from second one by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[ "1234/123456789/12/123", "1234/X/123456789/12/123"]})
 

df1 = df['a'].str.split('/', expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: f'Col{x+1}')
m = df1['Col2'].ne('X').to_numpy()
df1.iloc[m, 1:] = df1.iloc[m, 1:].shift(axis=1).fillna('')
print (df1)
   Col1 Col2       Col3 Col4 Col5
0  1234       123456789   12  123
1  1234    X  123456789   12  123
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Jezrael, I downvoted because there was no explanation of the code. It's great code, but I had to run it line by line myself to understand it. I think a comment or two explaining the approach would really help.

Comment: @Alan - OK, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, I upvoted. I wasn't aware of .shift(), so I'm glad to know it exists!

Comment: @jezrael what would be solution if I have some other characters in the strings such as uppercase letters A-B?

Comment: @MohammadAmir - If wnat test uppercase `A,B, X` change `m = df1['Col2'].ne('X').to_numpy()` to `m = ~df1['Col2'].isin(['A','B','X']).to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to just create a two dimensional list which you can then load as a DataFrame. Assuming here that your input strings fall in either one of two cases you describe: 4 columns or 5 columns, all with "/" as delimter. Using numpy's nan value for the empty entry.

```py
#converts one string to a list of column values
def stringToList(rowString):
    rowList = rowString.split("/")
    if len(rowList)==5:
        return(rowList)
    if len(rowList)==4:
        rowList = [rowList[0]] + [np.nan] + rowList[1::]
        return(rowList)

#converts list of strings to pd dataframe
def convertToDataFrame(listOfStrings):
    result = []
    for s in listOfStrings:
        result.append(stringToList(s))
    return pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Haven't tested it but let me know if it works. You can set column names with the `column=` argument in the pd.DataFrame method.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using regex, if you like:

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Create sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'s': ["1234/123456789/12/123", "1234/X/123456789/12/123"]})

# Build a named regex pattern. 
exp = re.compile(r'(?P<col1>\d+)\/(?P<col2>X)?\/?(?P<col3>\d+)\/(?P<col4>\d+)\/(?P<col5>\d+)')

# Extract parts into columns.
df['s'].str.extract(exp).replace(float('nan'), '')
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2         col3   col4    col5
0   1234            123456789     12     123
1   1234       X    123456789     12     123
```

Note:
The regex pattern used in this case, can be viewed as very liberal, or too rigid - depending on the exact use-case.  However, a fine feature of regex is that once the expected input text pattern is defined, the regex pattern can be easily updated to fit the purpose. Therefore, this particular pattern has been written to suit the use-case in the question.